# Get data up until last day of previous month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I've got an mysql-db with charges in it, with a datetime. Every month i want to create an invoice with all the charges from last month or earlier. So if it´s may 2nd, 5th or 30th 2012, i still only want the invoices from april 2012 or earlier. I've tried with date_sub, but it just subtracts a month, so it only invoices up to the same day of the previous month. How should i do this?

get * from Ads WHERE AdEnd > ??

Ty!

Answer (score 4):

I always found that if you subtract the day of the month in days from the current date, you'll get the last day of the previous month. For example, on the 15th of the month, subtract 15 days, and you'll end up with the last day of the previous month:

```
SELECT (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) DAY))
```

If `CURDATE()` is `2012-05-05` then the above returns `2012-04-30`.

So, to get Ads up to the last day of last month, do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ads
WHERE AdEnd <= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) DAY))
```

This works if AdEnd is a DATE, but if it's a DATETIME, you'll just want to do `less than the first of the month`, so you subtract one less day to get the first of the month like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ads
WHERE AdEnd < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY))
```

Comment: +1  Note that if `AdEnd` is really a DATETIME as the OP wrote, you'll need to do something akin to `... WHERE AdEnd < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY)`

Comment: Why the difference between date & datetime? Anyway, i'll try this! Post results when i get them. Thanks anyway for the help!

(by the way: actualy very simple when you think of it; i was substracting months, but this is way easier)

Comment: and by the looks of it, it works! Many thanks, Ami & Pilcrow!

Answer (score -1):

Try `date_diff`, for example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2008-11-30','2008-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

yields:

```
1
```